# Could not find or load main class with Ant build xml

Tags: java, xml, class, ant

I am pretty sure this is a silly mistake I am making somewhere, but I just can't see what is wrong.

I have am using Ant to build a jar from a main project and some external libraries.

This is my dir structure:

```
 project
 |--build/
 |--build.xml
 |--lib
 |--src
```

This is my build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project name="Proj1" default="default" basedir=".">
  <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Proj1</description>
   <property name="build.dir"   value="./build"/>
 <target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
 </target>

  <path id="class.path">
    <fileset dir="./lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="./build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes">
      <classpath refid="class.path" />
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="jar">
     <jar destfile="Proj1.jar" basedir="./build/classes" zip64Mode="always">
       <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
       <manifest>
          <attribute name="Main-Class" value="pt.nomad.Kafka.Main"/>
       </manifest>
     </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

When I run:

```
ant clean && ant compile && ant jar
```

Everything seems to work well, and a jar is created. However, if I try to execute the jar with:

```
java -jar Proj1.jar
```

It returns:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pt.nomad.Kafka.Main
```

Notice that I have defined a manifest in which I say that the Main Class is pt.nomad.Kafka.Main

If I run:

```
jar tf Proj1.jar | grep "pt/nomad/Kafka/Main"

pt/nomad/Kafka/Main$1.class
pt/nomad/Kafka/Main.class
```

I can see that the class is inside the jar with exactly the same path as I am providing to the manifest.

What is wrong with this setup?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I have added a ClassPath to manifest, but still it didn't work:

build.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="ROCM4.0" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project ROCM4.0.</description>

     <property name="build.dir"   value="./build"/>
     <property name="dist.dir"    value="."/>

     <target name="clean">
       <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
     </target>

     <path id="class.path">
      <fileset dir="./lib">
       <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
     </path>

     <target name="compile">
      <mkdir dir="./build/classes"/>
      <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes">
        <classpath refid="class.path" />
      </javac>
    </target>

    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="ROCM4.0.jar">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

<target name="jar">
   <jar destfile="ROCM4.0.jar" basedir="./build/classes" zip64Mode="always">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="pt.nomad.Kafka.Main"/>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
   </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the classes your `Main` class depends on is not on the classpath. You need to either add a `Class-Path` entry to the manifest, or specify the runtime classpath with `-cp` on the java command line.

Comment: I did try one of those approaches: `java -cp Proj1.jar pt.nomad.Kafka.Main` but it returned the same error. I will try the class path approach

Comment: the first approach still didn't work. I posted the updated xml file